# How to run Nuxt project in HTTPS?

Tags: nginx, https, nuxt.js

I managed turn nginx into https. When  I changed its configuration to support running of nuxt project. Then simply nginx is not opening the site.

I suspect because my nuxt project is not working in https. So how can I run nuxt in https.

What I did:
I reinstalled nginx I used letsencrypt bot to install certificates. Then I checked if nginx became https. 
Then I ran the nuxt in npm run start. Then changed the configuration of the nginx to support running nuxt. 
Then the page was not visible anymore.

Update 1:
I have uninstalled nginx.
I started the nuxt in production mode.
I changed the nginx according to get the proxy.

```
map $sent_http_content_type $expires {
    "text/html"                 epoch;
    "text/html; charset=utf-8"  epoch;
    default                     off;
}

server {
    listen          80;             # the port nginx is listening on
    server_name     example.me wwww.example.me;    # setup your domain here


    gzip            on;
    gzip_types      text/plain application/xml text/css application/javascript;
    gzip_min_length 1000;

    location / {
        expires $expires;

        proxy_redirect                      off;
        proxy_set_header Host               $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP          $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For    $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto  $scheme;
        proxy_read_timeout          1m;
        proxy_connect_timeout       1m;
        proxy_pass                          http://127.0.0.1:3000; # set the adress of the Node.js instance here
    }

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.me-0001/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.me-0001/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}
```

Now for some reason it works.. I have installed before the certificate maybe those certificates did not get uninstalled. It is actually difficult to understand how it started to work.

However it also allows now http also. I want to direct all http to https but when I put

```
map $sent_http_content_type $expires {
    "text/html"                 epoch;
    "text/html; charset=utf-8"  epoch;
    default                     off;
}

server {
    listen          80;             # the port nginx is listening on
    server_name     example.me wwww.example.me;    # setup your domain here
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;

    gzip            on;
    gzip_types      text/plain application/xml text/css application/javascript;
    gzip_min_length 1000;

    location / {
        expires $expires;

        proxy_redirect                      off;
        proxy_set_header Host               $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP          $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For    $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto  $scheme;
        proxy_read_timeout          1m;
        proxy_connect_timeout       1m;
        proxy_pass                          http://127.0.0.1:3000; # set the adress of the Node.js instance here
    }

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.me-0001/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.me-0001/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}
```

return 301 https://$host$request_uri; is causing everything crash

Now new issue is calling from https web service. But for this topic it is closed.

Comment: Nuxt not running in https shouldn't be the problem, I assume it runs on localhost or something and nginx proxys the url. It could be your nginx settings, perhaps you could show us your default file. What host are you using?

Comment: I did that and it worked. I am not sure why.

Comment: The issue is now directing all http incoming requests to https